# Into the Breach: Can't save on Nintendo Switch

Tags: nintendo-switch, into-the-breach

I have played a few times and gotten to the 2nd island with some upgrades. Any time I come back to the main screen of the game "Continue" is greyed out and I can only start a new game? How does one save their progress?

Comment: I assume you checked if you have space on your console, memory card or cloud save to save right?

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be an old bug, please first of all make sure that your game is up to date.

If it's up to date, then restart your console and you should be able to save normally.

Restart by:

- Holding down the power button for a few seconds
- Selecting Power Options
- Selecting Restart